# creating multiple new variables from means using grep or str_which in tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataset with multiple questionnaires. In the example below, var would be one questionnaire, and score would be another.

```
var_1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
var_2 <- c(5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
score_1 <- c(3, 1, 5, 2, 4)
score_2 <- c(2, 4, 1, 5, 3)

dat <- data.frame(var_1, var_2, score_1, score_2)
```

Using tidyverse, I want to create new variables which are calculated based on the mean of each questionnaire. I have tried both the following syntax:

```
dat %>%
  var <- rowMeans(grep("var", names(dat))) %>%
  score <- rowMeans(grep("score", names(dat)))
```

```
dat %>%
  var <- rowMeans(str_which(names(dat), "var")) %>%
  score <- rowMeans(str_which(names(dat), "score"))
```

However, both return the same error

```
Error in rowMeans(grep("var", names(dat))) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

But when I use grep in Base R with the following syntax, grep works fine.

```
dat$var <- rowMeans(dat[grep("var", names(dat))])
dat$score <- rowMeans(dat[grep("score", names(dat))])
```

However, since I have multiple questionnaires, typing out the above syntax for each questionnaire is tedious. Is there a way I can use the pipe with either grep or str_which to create my variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put them in `mutate` :

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(var = rowMeans(.[grep("var", names(.))]),
         score = rowMeans(.[grep("score", names(.))]))
```

---

Since you have multiple such questionnaires a better way is to use `split.default` which splits the columns based on the common part in their column name and then take row-wise mean.

```
cbind(dat, sapply(split.default(dat, sub('_.*', '', names(dat))), rowMeans))


#  var_1 var_2 score_1 score_2 score var
#1     1     5       3       2   2.5   3
#2     2     4       1       4   2.5   3
#3     3     3       5       1   3.0   3
#4     4     2       2       5   3.5   3
#5     5     1       4       3   3.5   3
```

Comment: Thank you very much! for the second solution using split.default, are you able to break down what the different parts of the syntax mean? I also just tried that on my dataset, but got the following error `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 'x' must be numeric` I suspect this could be because I also have non-questionnaire related items in my dataset, some of which also have underscores in them. Is there any way around this or would I need to create a new subset containing only the questionnaire items?

Comment: Yes, it is better if you create a separate dataset which have only questionnaire items. You can do this easily using subsetting columns i.e `df1 <- df[2:10]` to select columns from 2 to 10.  You can run the solution step by step to understand how it works. For eg `sub('_.*', '', names(dat))` see how it removes everything after underscore keep only main questionnaire items. Then run `split.default(dat, sub('_.*', '', names(dat)))` to see how it generates a list of dataframe where each dataframe is one question and so on.

Comment: Thank you! As a follow up, would it be possible to use the split.default option within the pipe? I added 2 extra dummy variables with underscores to my example and tried the following syntax `dat <- dat %>%
  select(3:6) %>%
  mutate(sapply(split.default(dat, sub('_.*', '', names(dat))), rowMeans)) ` but it returned the following error `Error: Column 'sapply(split.default(dat, sub("_.*", "", names(dat))), rowMeans)' must be length 5 (the number of rows) or one, not 15`

Comment: @pavlovsasimov You don't really need pipes here since the above is base R but if you still want to the above can be translated using pipes as `dat %>%
  split.default(sub('_.*', '', names(dat))) %>%
  sapply(rowMeans) %>%
  cbind(dat, .)`